# Cohomology of product Grassmann manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, grassmannian

For infinite complex Grassmann manifolds, we always have embedding $\tau\colon G_m\times G_n\to G_{m+n}$, then how to prove the induced homomorphism of cohomology rings $\tau^*\colon \mathsf{H}^*(G_{m+n};\mathbb{Z})\to\mathsf{H}^*(G_m\times G_n;\mathbb{Z})$ is injective?

Comment: What have you tried? What tools are available?

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, I assume that the induced homomorphism should always be injective for general case: A top space $X$ and its subspace $Y\subset X$. However, the cohomology functor $\mathsf{H}^*:\mathbf{Top}\to \mathbf{Ring}$ is not a left exact functor, so it is not necessary to preserve kernel (so is injective).

Comment: That assumption seems very wrong. Try the simplest case of $\Bbb CP^k\subset\Bbb CP^n$.

Comment: Do you know what the integral cohomology rings of complex Grassmannians look like?